# How to add/substract data from the database

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, addition

I have to add some data from the database together i am using this code to get it from the database

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `payments` ";
$query .= "WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ";
$query .= "AND complete = 1 ";
$query .= "AND type = 'script'";
$scripts = $database->query($query);
```

And i am using this foreach loop to try and add the amounts together:

```
foreach($scripts as $s) {
    $spendscripts + $s['amount'];
}
```

and this is what the DB looks like:

[image]

However when i echo $spendscripts its just empty and when i assign a default value its just that default value

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM ...`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE user_id =`, not `WHERE id =`?

Comment: You should print the SQL and try to execute in a client to see what's going wrong

Comment: You are not saving the data anywhere once you add them together.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! i didnt saw that but with this i couldnt get it to order by id and all those others but its fixed now thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 
`$spendscripts + $s['amount'];` 
to 
`$spendscripts  = $spendscripts + $s['amount'];`
and assign `$spendscripts` a default value of zero